# Embedded map in Google App Maker not rendering in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-app-maker

In Google App Maker I have an HTML widget with the following tag:

```
<div id='map'></div>
```

I create the map in the div like this:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
{
  zoom: 11,
  center: {lat: 41.879, lng: -87.624}
});
```

This works fine in Firefox and IE, but in Chrome the map just does not appear.  There are no errors, just an empty widget.  BTW, I can show the actual Map widget fine in Chrome but I need it to be in the HTML widget.

Has anybody run into this?

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Scott

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make it work in Chrome using this markup for the HTML widget:

```html
<div id='map' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'></div>
```

**Notes:**

1. I've enabled 'allowUnsafeHTML' option for the HTML widget.
2. To initialize maps API(google.maps.Map) I've just dropped App Maker Map widget on a page.
3. I called original code snippet in onClick handler of a button on a page.

```js
// onClick handler of some button on a page
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
          {
            zoom: 11,
            center: {lat: 41.879, lng: -87.624}
          });
```

Comment: I have the same styles, the unsafe HTML option checked, and it is calling the google.maps.Map() without errors.  Just no map appears in Chrome.  Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this works fine when the HTML widget is a fixed size.  When the widget is set to "fill parent" it does not render (but only in Chrome).

So this is a bug in either AppMaker or Chrome, probably the former.